# Using django-simple-captcha with django-lazysignup?

Tags: django, django-forms

This is the django-lazysignup forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm as UserCreationFormBase

class UserCreationForm(UserCreationFormBase):

    def get_credentials(self):
        return {
            'username': self.cleaned_data['username'],
            'password': self.cleaned_data['password1']}
```

How do I add django-simple-catcha (http://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to it? I tried the following but of course that doesn't work ;)

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm as UserCreationFormBase
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class UserCreationForm(UserCreationFormBase):

    def get_credentials(self):
        captcha = CaptchaField()
        return {
            'username': self.cleaned_data['username'],
            'password': self.cleaned_data['password1'],
            'captcha': captcha}
```

Any hint on how to add captcha on this registration form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's as easy as

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm as UserCreationFormBase
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class UserCreationForm(UserCreationFormBase):

    captcha = CaptchaField()

    def get_credentials(self):
        return {
            'username': self.cleaned_data['username'],
            'password': self.cleaned_data['password1']}
```

I use Pillow and had also to install `libfreetype6-dev`. Works like a charm!